# Can't convert xml string to w3c doc

Tags: java, xml, string, document, w3c

I want to convert an java string containing xml to a w3c dom document object.

I first searched all over the place and came up with some good examples here on stackoverflow.
But sadly I can get them working!

Apperently my code is not working 100%.

It seems like it parses the string but there are no values in the nodes.
This is what I got so far!

```
Document newDoc = null;

InputSource is = new InputSource();
is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(TestFiles.RSS_FEED_FILE_2));

DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder builder = null;
builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
newDoc = builder.parse(is);
```

When I do a sysout afterwards like this:

```
System.out.println(newDoc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("channel").item(0)
.getNodeValue());
```

I got null as output while using this sysout:

```
System.out.println(newDoc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("channel").item(0));
```

I got as output: [channel: null]

So I have an object else it would throw some null pointer exceptions but it doesn't contain any values inside ?!

The content of the constant is this :

```
public final static String RSS_FEED_FILE_2 =    "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" + 
                                            "<rss version=\"2.0\">\n" + 
                                            "<channel>\n" + 
                                            "<title>sunday</title>\n" + 
                                            "<link>http://www.google.nl</link>\n" + 
                                            "<pubDate>2012-02-05 20:58</pubDate>\n" + 
                                            "<lastBuildDate>2012-02-08 09:48</lastBuildDate>\n" + 
                                            "<description>blabla </description>\n" + 
                                            "<item>\n" + 
                                            "<title><![CDATA[title]]></title>\n" + 
                                            "<link><![CDATA[http://www.google.nl]]></link>\n" + 
                                            "<guid><![CDATA[2266610]]></guid>\n" + 
                                            "<source><![CDATA[sunday]]></source>\n" + 
                                            "<author><![CDATA[me]]></author>\n" + 
                                            "<description><![CDATA[blalbalavblabllllll!]]></description>\n" + 
                                            "</item>\n" + 
                                            "</channel>\n" + 
                                            "</rss>";
```

Does anybody have a solution or a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite a common gotcha.  The behaviour of `getNodeValue()` depends on the subclass of [Node](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html).  In the case of an `Element`, `getNodeValue()` will **always** return `null` (see the table in the `Node` javadoc for behaviour of other subclasses).

Consider using `getTextContent()` if you want to debug the XML document.

Comment: Or just don't use DOM. It's full of usability gotchas like this. Modern equivalents such as JDOM and XOM are superior in every respect.

Answer (score 1):

As you are trying to load an RSS XML string, I can suggest you to use RSS XSD from http://www.thearchitect.co.uk/schemas/rss-2_0.xsd. This will help you in loading the RSS string and giving you a better way to either edit data or transform it to any destinations like file. This will need JAXB to work although. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Using [jdom](http://www.jdom.org) takes a lot of pain of out processing XML, and it is usually my first port of call.

If using jdom is an option, then building the document is trivial.

```
SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuiler();
Document doc = builder.build(new StringReader(YOUR_XML_STRING));
```

The thing to be careful of is that this creates an org.jdom.Document object, which you then need to adapt in to a w3c document. Again this is quite easily achieved with the `org.jdom.output.DOMOutputter` class.